# Undesirable lines in "random" star generation

Tags: math, three.js

I'm creating a star field in a three.js scene. The code to generate the random positions of the stars is below. When the stars are rendered and the camera is pulled back enough from the center of the scene, there are a couple of visible "empty" tracks in the placement of the stars.

I'm assuming it has to do with the math in the `_addStars` method. Can anyone help me to tighten up the placement of the stars throughout the entire canvas?

Note: The canvas I have to work with is somewhere around an 8:1 ratio height:width. So just repositioning the camera is not an option.

**UPDATE:** I've added a fiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/scottwatkins/5zjoLLpx/5/

```
/** Method to generate the stars and place them in the particle system */
_addStars: function () {
    var starColors = [];
    var starGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    starGeometry.colors = starColors;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.totalStars; i++) {

        var x = 120 - Math.random() * 1040;
        var y = 480 - Math.random() * 1040;
        var z = 0 - Math.random() * 1040;

        starGeometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z ) );
        var starColor = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
        starColor.setRGB(
            .8 + Math.random() * .2,
            .8 + Math.random() * .2,
            .8 + Math.random() * .2);
        starColors.push(starColor)

    }

    var starMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {
        size: 2.0,
        map: this.starTexture,
        depthTest: false,
        depthWrite: false,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent : true,
        vertexColors: true
    } );

    this.particleSystem = new THREE.Points( starGeometry, starMaterial );

    this.scene.add(this.particleSystem);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the CanvasRenderer, if so you may need to set overdraw: true on textures

Comment: No the WebGLRenderer

Comment: Could be a bad random number generator.  Try calling `Math.random()` an extra time (and discarding that random number), and see if it moves the lines around...

Comment: @Neil Yes, I've tried changing the numbers and the only change that I see is that the lines move placement, but they are always present.

Comment: @comingstorm I have done as you have suggested and I don't see any change in the lines.

Comment: OK I'm interested to solve this, where can I get your code? Maybe a jsfiddle with your image as a base64 included?

Comment: @Neil I've added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottwatkins/5zjoLLpx/5/

Comment: Out of curiosity, what platforms are you able to duplicate this issue on? The fiddle works fine for me on OS X.

Comment: @WestLangley I'm on El Capitan (10.11.1) - viewing in Chrome 47.

Comment: I'm on (10.11.2) Chrome 47. Hmmm... Oh well, you have an answer you are happy with. : - )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be caused by `Math.random()` seems to work with `THREE.Math.random16()`

```
        var x = 120 - THREE.Math.random16() * 1040;
        var y = 480 - THREE.Math.random16() * 1040;
        var z = 0 - THREE.Math.random16() * 1040;
```

Here's what it says in the docs for `THREE.Math.random16()`:

*Random float from 0 to 1 with 16 bits of randomness.
Standard Math.random() creates repetitive patterns when applied over larger space.*

**Updated fiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/coder1012/5zjoLLpx/7/)

Comment: Any explanation as to how/why THREE.Math.random16 is any better than just Math.random? It still uses Math.random internally.

Comment: It looks like it is extending the range, if you're interested in this stuff check this out - https://medium.com/@betable/tifu-by-using-math-random-f1c308c4fd9d#.11bk8vrdh